# Is any absorbing set a neighbourhood of origin?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is any absorbing set $A\subset X$ (where $X$ is a normed space) a neighbourhood of $0_X$?

See the absorbing set definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set

Comment: How about $\{(x,y):y\le0\}\cup\{(x,y):x^2+(y-1)^2=1\}$?

Comment: I think the bounded set whose boundary is given by the curve $[0, 2 \pi] \to \mathbb{C}: x \mapsto x \exp(2 \pi i)$ together with the line $[0, 2 \pi] \to \mathbb{C}: x \mapsto x$ should work

That's some kind of spiral starting at zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your examples!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed space over $\mathbb{K}$, $\mathbb{K}$ being either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and $\varphi$ a linear functional on $X$.  Then $$U=\varphi^{-1}(\{\alpha\in \mathbb{K} ~:~|\alpha|<1\})$$ is absorbing.  In fact, it is even balanced.  Now $U$ is a neighbourhood of $0_X$ if and only if $\varphi$ is bounded.

According to the abstract of [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/advgeom.2016.16.issue-4/advgeom-2016-0010/advgeom-2016-0010.xml), in every infinite dimensional normed space, there exists a balanced and absorbing set with empty interior.